# Why should we use join() function while reversing a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

what is the purpose of **''.join()**  here

```
print(''.join(reversed(a)))
```

can't we reverse a string only with reversed function

```
print(reversed("python"))
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your specific question, but you can reverse a string without `join` and `reversed`: `revstring = mystring[::-1]`.

Comment: Have you tried calling the code?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do it simply by calling `reversed`. `reversed` returns an special `reversed` iterator object, something that needs to be iterated through in order to produce it's elements.

Not supplying it to `.join` here will just print out the confusing `repr` of the `reversed` object: `<reversed object at 0x7f2ba02be320>`.

Calling `"".join`, which takes an iterable as an argument, consumes the `reversed` object and joins the elements producing the string you see.

Take note that there's other ways to consume it without `join` that result in a different object, `list`, for example, will take the `reversed` object and create a list out of the elements it produces:

```
a = reversed('abcd')
print(list(a))
['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

If you need a string in the end, then the best option is `.join`.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate `str` same as `list`:

```
a = 'abcd'
a[::-1] #'dcba'
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `join` is to take an iterable and join it by a delimiter to produce a string:

```
''.join(reversed(a))
```

`a` can be an iterable that supports the iteration protocol or an object that overloads `__getitem__`. That is, any object that you would normally want to use in a `for` loop or comprehension or you would like to iterate on to produce its result and make them as a string, that object could possibly be a potential value for `join`.

`reversed` returns an object that you need to iterate on in order to fetch its values in `join`. so  `''.join(reversed(a))` means the following: reverse `a` first and then iterate on the resulting object of `reversed` and join each extracted object by delimiter specified by `join`, in your case it's just an empty string.

> *can't we reverse a string only with reversed function?*

Not really! You can reverse a string using this expression instead of `reversed` function: `'stackoverflow'[::-1]`. As usual, there could be several ways to achieve the same effects in programming.